# Puppet configuration using augeas fails if combined with notify

Tags: puppet, configuration-management, augeas

I'm having a problem with the following Puppet manifest, which is meant
to enable the `passwdqc` pam module on a RHEL-6 system (this is using
Puppet 0.25.5 and augeas 0.7.2):

```
augeas { 'authconfig':
        context => '/files/etc/sysconfig/authconfig',
        changes => [
                'set USEPASSWDQC yes',
                'set USECRACKLIB no',
                ],
        notify  => Exec['authconfig-all'],
}

exec { 'authconfig-all':
        command         => '/usr/sbin/authconfig --updateall',
        refreshonly     => true,
}
```

If I run this manifest, it appears to complete successfully:

```
info: Applying configuration version '1311189237'
notice: //Augeas[authconfig]/returns: executed successfully
info: //Augeas[authconfig]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[authconfig-all]
notice: //Exec[authconfig-all]: Triggering 'refresh' from 1 dependencies
```

But if I examine the target file, the changes have not been applied:

```
# egrep 'PASSWDQC|CRACKLIB' /etc/sysconfig/authconfig
USECRACKLIB=yes
USEPASSWDQC=no
```

If I remove the `notify => ...` line from the manifest, it works
exactly as intended.  That is, given this:

```
augeas { 'authconfig':
        context => '/files/etc/sysconfig/authconfig',
        changes => [
                'set USEPASSWDQC yes',
                'set USECRACKLIB no',
                ],
}
```

The changes are successfully saved:

```
# puppet /path/to/manifest.pp
info: Applying configuration version '1311189502'
notice: //Augeas[authconfig]/returns: executed successfully

# egrep 'PASSWDQC|CRACKLIB' /etc/sysconfig/authconfig
USECRACKLIB=no
USEPASSWDQC=yes
```

Any idea what's going on here?  Obviously puppet *believes* that the
change is being made the first time around, but it's not actually
getting saved to disk.  We have other configurations using augeas and
notify operations that work just fine; we haven't been able to figure
out why this is failing.  Note that the same problem exists if I replace `notify` on the augeas operation with `subscribe` on the corresponding `exec` definition.

My current plan is to build packages out of more recent versions of
puppet and augeas and see if the problem will Magically Go Away.

**UPDATE**: freiheit points out that `authconfig` appears to be overwriting this file.  Oddly enough, under CentOS 5, modifying `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig` and then running `authconfig --updateall` was exactly the correct procedure.  This is what we're actually using in our legacy Kickstart.

So apparently the RHEL6 upgrade has made `authconfig` behave in strange and unhelpful ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the answer is that the behavior of the `authconfig` command changed between RHEL5 and RHEL6.  In RHEL6, instead of *reading* `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig` and then generating the configuration, `authconfig` in RHEL6 appears to parse each individual configuration file that it manages, and then *generates* `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig` as a record of the current state.

This means that one has to edit configuration files directly if one is either (a) trying to avoid running the `authconfig` command, or (b) trying to take advantage of features that aren't supported on the `authconfig` command line.

This is what I ended up with to enabled the `passwdqc` PAM module:

```
augeas { 'pam_passwdqc':
    context => '/files/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac/',
    changes => [
        'rm *[module="pam_cracklib.so"]',
        'ins 9999 before *[type="password"][module="pam_unix.so"]',
        'set 9999/type password',
        'set 9999/control requisite',
        'set 9999/module pam_passwdqc.so',
        'set 9999/argument enforce=everyone',
    ],
    onlyif  => 'match *[module="pam_passwdqc.so"] size == 0',
    notify  => Exec['authconfig-update-all'],
}

exec { 'authconfig-update-all':
    command     => '/usr/sbin/authconfig --updateall',
    refreshonly => true,
}
```

If you find yourself reading this answer, I'd love to hear your comments on whether or not this is sane way of handling things.  I'm new to Puppet so I'm still feeling my way around the way things work.

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr/sbin/authconfig --updateall` command writes to /etc/sysconfig/authconfig -- You can confirm this with a simple "ls -l".  It's overwriting the changes that puppet/augeas makes.

If it were me, I'd handle this by figuring out what the underlying changes you need are and making those, which I believe are all to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac`. That would also make it trivial to control the various parameters to the module.

Comment: That is frustrating, because information elsewhere (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=605857#c1) suggested just the opposite.  I'm new to Puppet, but it doesn't seem to very good at making *edits* to a file (other than with augeas), whereas it's very good at replacing files.  This makes it difficult to make these changes directly to `system-auth-ac`, because I only want to make this one change and leave any other user modifications in place.  It would be easy with `sed`. but that's the sort of thing we're trying to avoid...

Comment: Hmmm, I see that there is an augeas "lens" for pam configuration files.  Maybe I can make that work.